# Workstation to server ping/connection not working(*more in description)

Tags: windows, networking, connection

While am pinging from workstation to the server it doesn't ping and showing `destination host unreachable`. However when am pinging from server it works, and now if I am pinging from the workstation it also works. And this is only for few minutes; the workstation goes to the old state after a few sec.

***In short if I need connection to server I am required to first ping from the server to workstation.*** Connection between other devices in the network works fine.

Firewalls are off, machines are in same network, workstation is not added to the domain.

**EDIT3:** The server PC got another NIC and I enabled that. It's IP is `192.168.2.106`. Now the connection is seamless to `.106` and its still the same with `.68`(the other NIC which is every other person in the network connected to).

EDIT1: more details

When I ping from the server to the workstation it is creating an arp cache entry in the workstation for the server. And can access the server from workstation. After couple of minutes the entry for the server gets deleted from the arp cache and now it is unreachable. The connection can only be restored when I ping from server to workstation.

EDIT2:

***Workstation***: windows 7 Ultimate

ipconfig info:

[image]

***Server***: Windows Server 2012 R2

ipconfig info:

[image]

Comment: Worst 'question' of November - bravo!

Comment: Why do you care if ping works or not? What services are being provided by the server and are those services available and accessible? If so, then great... forget about ping and get on with your life. If not, then troubleshoot those services using appropriate tools and methods.

Comment: @Chopper3 English is not my first language help me improve the question and resolve the issue.

Comment: @joeqwerty by ping I meant basic connectivity. Not able to access the shared files. The address automatically gets deleted form arp cache.

Comment: It's not your language that's the problem, you've provided us with almost zero information to help you - if you go to a doctor and say 'I'm in pain' you're going to have to work with them to narrow it down right? MORE DETAILS!

Comment: @Chopper3 Not even that.  It's like going to a doctor and complaining that your car doesn't work, when the issue is that you broke your leg in a car accident.

Comment: @Chopper3 the issue itself is quiet strange to me, don't know how to give enough info. All I can see is when I ping from the server to the workstation it is creating an arp cache entry in the workstation for the server. And can access the server from workstation. After couple of minutes the entry for the server gets deleted from the arp cache and now it is unreachable. The connection can only be restored when I ping from server to workstation.

Comment: As an example you've not even mentioned what exact operating systems both ends are, their ipconfig/ifconfig details - throw us a bone here!

Comment: @Chopper3 I have edited my question with this info. Please refer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason 'network discovery' was turned off in the server and wasn't able to turn that on. Did [this solution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2722035) from Microsoft support portal and everything is fine with the universe again.

Solution from Microsoft support portal:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start by clearing your ARP cache (arp -d -a) and verify your gateway with a ping.

If you're able to do that, ping the destination, view the arp cache and verify (arp -a) the IP address/MAC information is correct. Once the ping stops (Destination Host Unreachable), verify the arp cache again and see what changed.

You should find that a device on this network is causing a conflict.

Comment: After deleting the arp cache the issue persists. While pinging to the server no new entry is created in the cache. And new entries are created if I ping to other machines. The entry for the server is created only when I ping from the server to workstation.

Comment: We may need to have a look at your ipconfig on both sides; although, this appears to be a Windows Firewall or IP conflict on your network.